# Get checkbox within div value from java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I can't get the checkbox value of "no_del_file" into the servlet.

here is my JSP:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>List of Command menu</title>


 </head>
 <body>
<div><b>${reply}</b></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu">
<form action="runButtonCommand" method="post" name="myform"> 
<a href="runButtonCommand?param1=list apps" >List1</a><br/><br/>
<a href="runButtonCommand?param1=list data" >List2</a><br/><br/>
<br/><br/>

no del: 

<%String test = (String)request.getParameter("no_del_file"); %>
<%String checked = "";%>

<% 
if ("on".equals(test)) {
    checked="checked=\"on\"";

} %>
<input type="checkbox" name="no_del_file" <%=checked%>>
<br />

</form>

</div>
<div id="output">
  <p>Output:</p>
  <textarea style="resize: none;" data-role="none" rows="40" cols="120" name="outputarea">
  ${data}
  </textarea>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Servlet part where I try to get the checkbox value:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String[] tester= request.getParameterValues("no_del_file");
    System.out.println("Start: "+tester);
    performTask(request, response);
}
```

However it doesn't matter if I use getParameterValues, getParameter or getAttribute I always get null if checked or unchecked. How can I get that value?

Thanks for your help.

Viking

Comment: if you're always getting null then it means you're not sending the value to the servlet. If you check the headers in the network view of your browser when you submit, do you see the "no_del_file" value there ?

Comment: Your checkbox `input` element needs a value attribute. When checked, that value will be submitted with the form. For example, if you have `<input type="checkbox" name="no_del_file" value="hello"/>`, then `request.getParameterValues()` will return `["hello"]`. See the [checkbox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Comment: I am setting the value with <%=checked%> since it is not always checked and the form must keep as is after being submitted

Comment: No, you're setting the checked state via the `checked` attribute. See the section called **Value** in the [MDN checkbox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).